# Can create commands with \section*{} but not \subsection*{}?

Tags: macros, sectioning

I'm trying to create some commands in the `article` document class that will save keystrokes when I TeX my homework. I end up typing `\section*{Exercise #}` repeatedly, so I created a macro:

```
\newcommand{\exer}[1]{\section*{Exercise #1}}
```

It works fine, however, when I make a similar command for sub-problems:

```
\newcommand{\part}[1]{\subsection*{Part #1}}
```

It doesn't work as illustrated below. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are ignoring an error message due to `\newcommand{\part}` (see the red icon above the PDF viewer in Overleaf). `\part` is already defined, so `\newcommand{\part}` raises an error and does nothing. Either use `\renewcommand` or use a different name

Comment: Not related to the problem directly, which Phelype has pinpointed, but you might want to do this a bit less manually, using a package designed for this kind of thing (See [Comparing packages which facilitate typesetting exercises and solutions: exercise vs. answers vs. probsoln](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/22269)), or at least use enumerated lists with `enumitem`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This resolved the issue. Thank you and apologies for asking something trivial.

Comment: @GregórBataille No problem at all. It happens :-)